# How to check if list values inside a dictionary are equal?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which is checked every so often in a loop. The loop should **determine** if the lists inside the dictionary are all equal. I tried using this function (below) - will print 1 if the values are all equal.

```
def equalDict(values):
    sample = []
    for i in values:
        for j in i:
            sample.append(str(j))
    
    return (len(set(sample)))
```

the values parameter contains somedict.values() and the dictionary contains these key value pairs:

```
sample = {'w0':[0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004],'w1': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004],'w2': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], 'w3': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]}
```

while all of these are the same, the function returns 2 instead of 1. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have multiple keys that are the same; in reality, your `sample` dictionary only has one key and one list. Your code produces the result 2 because you are checking the size of the set `{'w', '0'}`.

Comment: ah, my bad the keys should be increasing by 1. I mistyped

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as it is, is not checking that all the lists are equal. It's returning the total count of unique elements across all lists.

With your example:

```
sample = {'w0':[0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004],'w1': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004],'w2': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], 'w3': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]}
```

`equalDict(sample.values())` computes and returns `len({0.2, 0.30000000004})` which is `2`.

---

To check that the elements of a list are all equal, you can do:

```
all_equal = len(set(elements)) == 1
```

if and only if each element in `elements` is hashable/immutable. In this case, `elements` is a list of list -- i.e. each element is a list -- list's aren't hashable/immutable, so you'd get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` if you tied:

```
elements = [[0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]]
all_equal = len(set(elements)) == 1 # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

One workaround is to turn each element/list into a tuple (tuple's are hashable/immutable):

Case where elements are all equal:

```
elements = [[0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]]
elements = map(tuple, elements)
all_equal = len(set(elements)) == 1
print(all_equal) # True
```

Case where elements are not all equal

```
elements = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]]
elements = map(tuple, elements)
all_equal = len(set(elements)) == 1
print(all_equal) # False
```

This will only work if each element in `elements` is a list of hashable/immutable values, so the following would cause an error:

```
elements = [[0.1, 0.2, [1, 2]], [0.2, 0.2, [1, 2]], [0.2, 0.2, [1, 2]]]
elements = map(tuple, elements)
all_equal = len(set(elements)) == 1
print(all_equal) # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

but that doesn't seem to be your use case.

---

In summary:

```
def all_equal(elements):
    elements = map(tuple, elements)
    return len(set(elements)) == 1
```

will work for your use case where `elements` is a list of list of hashable/immutable values such as `[[0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This actually solves the infinite loop I am having lol. Also explains a lot as to why the function was not working

Comment: Beautiful solutions and explanations, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you can't just use `==`?

```
>>> a = ["a", 2, 3]
>>> b = ["a", 2, 3]
>>> a == b
True
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> a == b
False
```

So for your specific case,

```
sample = {'w0':[0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004],'w1': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004],'w2': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004], 'w3': [0.2, 0.2, 0.30000000004]}

keys = list(sample.keys())

value = True
for key in keys[1:]:
    if sample[keys[0]]!=sample[key]:
        value = False
        break

print(value)
```

Comment: To be honest, I got too fixated on the function I made, and the fact that I kinda suck in coding did not help so... yeah. In any case, thanks for the answer. It works just as well as the commenter

Answer (score 0):

joseville's solution is very informative and correct. In this situation I use a custom function as:

```
def compare(self, mydict): 
    for list1 in mydict.values():
        for list2 in mydict.values():
            if not list1 == list2:
                # return false, give warning, break etc.
```

I loop through dictionary values with respect to a dictionary test value and compare.